# Performance issue with "Dive Into SpriteKit" example code

Tags: timer, sprite-kit

I made a basic SpriteKit game with my son using step-by-step tutorial from [Dive Into SpriteKit book by Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/store/dive-into-spritekit.).

The game is just one SKScene that draws a ship, a bunch of space junk, and provides basic control. When the game is over, we follow instructions from the book and do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately with each new game scene FPS goes down and after ~20 game overs on my iPad the game is unplayable. I guess something is not properly de-initialized, but I am not sure where to look and how to fix this.

I checked "canonical" implementation form the book and they all have exactly the same issue on iOS 12.

Our [complete implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/ilyabelikin/DiveIntoSpriteKit/tree/master/Junkover).

I will appreciate advice on how to manage scenes lifecycle to keep performance.

Comment: I would start by invalidating those timers and setting them to nil in `gameOver`. Better yet, you should replace them with `SKAction`s.

Comment: @0x141E thank you! I tried setting timers to zero, but it looks like it does not have any effect. Game performance still degrades up to one digit FPS and complete freezings ~ 30th game over.

Comment: @0x141E ah, I notice now that you said "invalidate and set to nil", googled, doing invalidation on both timers now and it fixed the performance degradation issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Re-wrote with SKAction.repeatForever(), it is much nice this way. Thanks! @0x141E, should I add the answer here?

Comment: You can also replace the `DispatchQueue` code with an `SKAction` or two.

Comment: It's a good idea to add `deinit {print("deinit")}` to your class when trying to determine if the memory allocated to the class is released.

Comment: @0x141E thanks! I added deinit and it never called. It looks like each new scenes stays behind currently eating up the memory :/

Comment: @0x141E Why it make sense to replace `DispatchQueue` with `SKAction`? With timer it is very clear that using SKAction makes it easier to manage and seems like a correct way to do it. Is `DispatchQueue` is problematic somehow?

Comment: Add `removeAllActions()` to `gameOver`.

Comment: @0x141E I see, so similar to `Timer` that need `invalidation()` the `SKAction` need to be removed. I tested it in a branch, and when we do invalidation on the timers, there is no memory leak as well as when we do `removeAllActions()`. So it seems to be very similar in this case. What is the advantage of using `SKAction` over `Timer` or `DispatchQueue`? Is it just a wrapper for the same things or it does something differently? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @0x141E for the solution and the advices!

The issue was with the timer (which is in use to add nodes to the scene). A timer runs in Run Loop and have to be invalidated with:

```
timer!.invalidate()
```

Adding the invalidation in GameOver for both timers solved the major performance degradation issue as well as the memory leak.

Following the advice, we learned a bit more about SKAction, and another way of creating space junk on schedule seems to be:

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.run(createEnemy),
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.45)
    ])))
```

In this case we still need to make sure we do stop all the actions in the GameOver.

```
removeAllActions()
```